# DateFormat to display DateObject sub-second data?

Tags: date-and-time

Is there a `DateFormat` or other option to display milliseconds?

```
DateObject["2022-04-18T14:02:10.326"]
```

[image: formatted display down to the second resolution]

Sub-second information appears to be readable only using `FullForm`:

```
"2022-04-18T14:02:10.326" // DateObject // FullForm

(* Out: DateObject[List[2022, 4, 18, 14, 2, 10.326`], "Instant", "Gregorian", -4.`] *)
```

Comment: You can use DateFormat: `DateObject["2022-04-18T14:02:10.326", 
 DateFormat -> {"DayNameShort", " ", "Day", " ", "MonthNameShort", 
   " ", "Year", " ", "Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second", ".", 
   "Millisecond"}]`

Comment: thanks Carl, works, and w/ SetOptions

Comment: @CarlWoll Maybe we can add your comment as an answer?